# why virtual environment does not work from project folder and gives error "ImportError: DLL load failed" but works from Python folder?

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc, python-venv

If I create a project and place virtual environment inside the project folder, then installing some packages gives me an Import error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could > not be found
```

My project location:  `\\Documents\path\to\my\MyProject`

But if I create virtual environment in a folder where Python is installed then it works fine.

[image]

Python located: `C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe`

So why I am not able to fully utilize virtual environment placing it in a project folder?

After I activate virtualenv, shouldn't I be able to run python from any directory, even outside of my project?

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: When do you get the error from within your activated project venv? Is it when you try to launch Python, or is it when you try to `import pyodbc`?

Comment: when I try to import pyodbc. But it's not just pyodbc package, same error importing other packages.